# How to Pass NULL Data Type?

Tags: java, .net, database, null

What is the datatype for `NULL` when passing that value for no data into a database?

Answer (score 6):

There is **NO** data type of NULL. NULL itself means **ABSENCE** of data. When there is no data, how can it have type?

Comment: Yeah, this is what I had to be taught when I joined my company.  NULL is the absence, it is not a type, however it can be represented by types (i.e. the .NET framework has DBNull.Value as a representation of the NULL value).

Comment: Yes I agree. In any technology you must have *something* to represent it. (You cant represent nothing with nothing). But as a concept, NULL means "nothing". Literally!

Comment: @Hemant, while that is a good database definition of NULL, that abstract concept is represented by an actual value.  Assuming that Prabhahar wants to pass the value in some programming language to the database, there will be an associated database driver API which will have an implementation of passing NULL.

Comment: I don't agree that Null means "an absence of a value". Rather, it is a special value (in addition to any ordinary possible value associated with the datatype) which is subject to special logic and handling. It is possible to explicitly record that a normal input to the computer system was not available at the time the record was made - and that record is then a present record with a present Null value.

Answer (score 3):

Null does not have a specific data type in SQL.  Any nullable column or variable can contain null.  Null is never equal or unequal to anything.  You can cast a variable holding null to another variable and get null, for example:

```
declare @a integer
set @a = null
select convert (float, @a)

----------------------
NULL

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually NULL is its own datatype - the type of 1 is "INTEGER", the type of the type of NULL is "NULL"

Answer (score 1):

Datatype for `NULL` is as meaningless as datatype for `0`: it can be `INTEGER`, `FLOAT` or a `VARCHAR`. You cannot tell it just from the value.

`NULL` is legitimate value in almost every datatype domain, which means the absence of actual value.

It's also meaningless to discuss datatypes out of context of certain `RDBMS`.

In `SQLite`, for instance, datatypes are value-bound, not column-bound, and `NULL` is a first-class datatype per se.

In `Oracle`, the datatypes are more strictly defined. For instance, this query works:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(dt, i)
FROM    (
        SELECT  CAST(NULL AS DATE) AS dt, CAST(NULL AS DATE) i
        FROM    dual
        ) q
```

and this does not:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(dt, i)
FROM    (
        SELECT  CAST(NULL AS DATE) AS dt, CAST(NULL AS NUMBER) i
        FROM    dual
        ) q
```

, because the latter query returns two columns of different datatypes, both of them having values of `NULL`, and `COALESCE` requires both arguments to have same datatype.

It's better to say that a `NULL` of any datatype can be implicitly converted to a `NULL` on another datatype.

For instance, a `VARCHAR` can be implicitly converted to a `INTEGER` if it has value of `0`, but cannot if it has value of `'some_string'`.

For `NULL`'s, any datatype can be implicitly converted to any other datatype, if the implicit conversion between them is allowed at all.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL a NULL is a "mark" (something other than a value) that can apply to any SQL type. So it is orthogonal to type.

Answer (score 0):

NULL is the value for 'undefined'. So any type in a database can be 'undefined', as it's a property of the column: a value of a row for the specific column can be 'undefined' which means it's 'NULL', no matter what the type is. As long as the column is nullable.

Answer (score 0):

I think DBNULL or NULL is a special type.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question defeats itself.  If NULL had a datatype, wouldn't you be forced to change it with every instantiation outside of its default.  For example, when you create it as a character, but then force it into an object's value?

`NULL==NULL`

That is all.

Comment: At risk of being contrary, most platforms that fully support null would return NULL to the comparison "NULL == NULL", not in fact true :) This makes your above comparison invalid, as _any_ comparison with NULL is meaningless, except checking if it's null with ...IS NULL

Comment: This made me smile, and I see what you're saying. Chalk one up for learning something **new** everyday.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in PowerShell comparing $null -eq $null gives False. 
Also, -not $null will give you True, so here it seems to be reprezented as False. I know, PowerShell might not be a good example, but still :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually SQL `NULL` does not have a type associated with it. However there are exceptions. Database engines postgresql and derby (javadb) require that null has a type. In other words they do not support untyped null. So query conditions like `NULL IS NULL` may fail. Here, `NULL` must be given a type, the expected type of the target that processes the `NULL` value. In this case this appears silly because there is no target and this can be counterproductive.

See [CAST function: -- you must cast NULL as a data type to use it](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefsqlj33562.html)

See [Queries with guarded null Parameter fail](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-5629) and [Add support for setObject(arg, null)](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/3)

Please vote for these issues so that the odd database engines change their ways.

Answer (score 0):

Prabhahar, each type of database driver has its own way of handling `NULL`.  You will have to examine the driver API for the specific database.

For example if you are using the Java Derby database, simply pass in the Java native type, null as shown in [Ian Bjorhovde's answer to "Derby's Handling of NULL Values"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4909606/212950):

```
insert into T_AUTHOR (
  ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, 
  DATE_OF_BIRTH, YEAR_OF_BIRTH, ADDRESS) 
VALUES ( 
  1000, 'Lukas', 'Eder', 
  '1981-07-10', null, null 
);
```

Here is another `null` example of [JDBC:Inserting null to Integer column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14514632/212950):

```
pst.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

Answer (score -1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)

Answer (score -1):

`NULL` can be cast (converted) to any data type yet data type comparisons with `NULL` always return `FALSE`.

Comment: -1, because comparisons with NULL result in NULL not in FALSE. In an IF statement in PL/SQL, NULL is treated like FALSE, but NOT NULL is NULL, not TRUE

Comment: the same goes for WHERE clauses etc.