# Inserting null to an Integer column using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have an sql column `PROTOCOL`, it is nullable and has a constraint on the table

```
PROTOCOL IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Also since it is nullable, I want to set and get null values into table

But I cannot do `setInt` and `getInt` as null. How to set a null to column as null using JDBC

```
setInt(4,null);
```

Comment: Have you tried the setObject() method?

Comment: Try `setObject(4, null)`.

Comment: @BheshGurung Bah, beat me to it =p

Comment: How can i get it after setting to null ;Will getInt Return null?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try using.

```
   pst.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);  //pst is prepared statement instance.
```

[Interface PreparedStatement.setNull API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull-int-int-)

[Mapping of java.sql.Types to SQL types](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.3.3.0/ref/rrefjdbc20377.html)

P.S. : Edited to reflect Java 8 updates.

Comment: How can i get it  after setting to null ;Will getInt Return null?

Comment: @constantlearner I never had a occasion to use this, but surely you can try.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice only if you know in advance you want to insert `null`.

Answer (score 28):

In addition to [Smit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14514632/2448440):

If you want to insert an `Integer`-object into a database that may be `null`, you can use

```
statement.setObject(4, yourObject, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

instead of

```
if (yourObject == null) {
    statement.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
else {
    statement.setInt(4, yourObject);
}
```

Comment: new in java8?  `statement.setObject(4, yourObject, java.sql.JDBCType.INTEGER);`

Comment: You actually don't need to provide the JDBCType | sql.Types jdbc figures it out by itself. Or at least the MSSQL driver does.

Comment: In DB2, this won't  work: 
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: setObject not implemented

Comment: @Jaja are you referring to my answer, or to the comment from Marthinus Engelbrecht?

Comment: @Qw3ry, NOT referring to your answer, I mean, there should be java.sql.Types instead of java.sql.JDBCType