# set prepared statement parameter where NOT NULL java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

To perform an sql query in java using prepared statement, I know that you do it like this:

```
Connection con=UserModel.getConnection();  
String sql = "UPDATE users SET firstname=?,lastname=? WHERE id=?";
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql); 

ps.setString(1,u.getFirstname());  
ps.setString(2,u.getLastname());  
ps.setString(3,u.getId());
```

Where the first parameters in the setString method represent the order of the values to go into the sql statement in places where you have the ? sign.

Now what I want to do is select from users table **where role is NOT NULL**. Something like this:

```
Connection con = UserModel.getConnection();  
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE role=?");
ps.setString(1,not_null); // ***here***
```

How do I select where role is not null? That is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sql with a where clause of:

```
where role is not null
```

Using = to compare something to null won’t work. The setNull on PreparedStatement - see [JDBC:Inserting null to Integer column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14514589) - substitutes the null, but that doesn’t help here because the where clause condition is always false. For why, see [Why does NULL = NULL evaluate to false in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1843451/217324)

Answer (score -1):

```
Connection con = UserModel.getConnection();  
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE role is NOT NULL");
ps.executeQuery();
```

Use this not null for the respective column name role

Comment: you need to specify in the query itself for NOT NULL and execute directly.