# cannot set null to a unique column

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, null, unique-constraint

so this is my table

```
CREATE TABLE "client" (
"id"    INTEGER,
"name"  TEXT COLLATE NOCASE,
"surname"   TEXT COLLATE NOCASE,
"number"    TEXT UNIQUE COLLATE NOCASE,
"car_brand" TEXT,
"modele"    TEXT,
"phone_nbr" TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT));
```

when im adding a new statment from my java application i can add only one time NULL to the column number but i can add many nulls from the db browser
this is the code that i use

```
String number = tf_number.getText();
      if(tf_number.getText().trim().isEmpty())
          number = null;
    String name = tf_name.getText();
    String surname = tf_surname.getText();
    String phoneNbr = tf_phoneNbr.getText();
    String car_brand = tf_brand.getText();
    String modele = tf_modele.getText();
    Client c = new Client(name, surname, number, car_brand, modele, phoneNbr);
    ClientCRUD pcd = new ClientCRUD();
    pcd.addClient(p);
```

and this is the sql error

> [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE]  A UNIQUE constraint failed (UNIQUE constraint failed: client.number)

this is the addClient() fonction

```
public void addClient(Client t) {
try {
        
    String requete = "INSERT INTO CLIENT(name,surname,number,car_brand,MODELE,phone_nbr)"
    + "VALUES ('"+t.getClientName()+"','"+t.getClientSurname()+"','"+t.getNumber()+"',"
            + "'"+t.getCarBrand()+"','"+t.getModele()+"','"+t.getPhone()+"')";
    Statement st = MyConnection.getInstance().getCnx()
                .createStatement();

        st.executeUpdate(requete);
        System.out.println("Client added");
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    }
```

any solution ?

Comment: I guess you are using the SQLite database since SQLite now allows null values for the Unique fields. But MySQL does support a null value for the unique field.

Comment: @ShofiullahBabor Im using SQLITE

Comment: That's why you can't do that

Comment: Post the code for the addClient() method.

Comment: @ShofiullahBabor can you explain more ?

Comment: yeah sure ask, please?

Comment: My guess is that your Java code insert the string "null" and not a real null like your browser does.   So because it is unique, only one string "null" can exist in that column.

Comment: @forpas added !

Comment: @PamStums yeah maybe ! any idea how to insert real null ?

Comment: @ShofiullahBabor im using SQLITE and it allows the nulls value in unique so what the problem that that's why i cant do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void save(Person person) {
    String query = "INSERT INTO person_info (" +
            " name_p, " +
            " age, " +
            " address, " +
            " email " +
            ")" +
            "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";

    try(Connection connection = dbConnection.getConnection()) {
        PreparedStatement prepStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);

        prepStatement.setString(1, person.getName());
        prepStatement.setInt(2, person.getAge());
        prepStatement.setString(3, person.getAddress());
        prepStatement.setString(4, null);

        prepStatement.execute();
    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

##This will solve your problem

Comment: @ Shofiullah,  Thanks for the complete example!

Comment: thanks! now it works

Comment: `prepStatement.setString(4, null);` - Doesn't this cause non-null values to be lost?

Answer (score 0):

You code inserts the string "null" and not a real null like your browser do.
So there can be only 1 string with value "null" in that unique column.

You can use preparedStatement with parameters instead of the statement you use.
E.g:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql))
```

This answers how to insert null using prepared statement: [Insert null using prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514589/inserting-null-to-an-integer-column-using-jdbc)

And your sql string for the query should have the parameters.
See more about prepared statements: [Prepared Statements Tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/preparedstatement.html)

Comment: yes maybe ! any idea how to insert real null ?

Comment: See the tutorial I've referred to.

Comment: I will check it and tell you the result, thanks!

Comment: I've added a reference to another answer on how to insert a null using prepared statement.